# AngularJS2 and Socket.io, is this approach be improved?

Tags: socket.io, angular

In my index.html I inserted the Socket.io script:

```
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>
```

This is a part of my component:

```
import {Component, OnInit, AfterContentInit} from 'angular2/core';
@Component({
  selector: '[cssEditor]',
  templateUrl: '/app/cssEditor/cssEditor.html'
})

export class cssEditor {
  cssData = {
    'body-bg':'#fff',
    'text-color':'#000'
  };

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    // for emit to the server
    this.socket.on('connect', () =>
      this.socket.emit('myCssData',this.cssData);
    );
    // for listening to the server
    this.socket.on('recordOK', (data) =>
      console.log(data);
    );
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.socket = io('http://localhost:2000');
  }
}
```

I entered the events servers listening in 'ngAfterContentInit'. This code works for me very well, but do you think that the best way?

Comment: I think this makes sense given the life cycle hooks available. There ins't a need to communicate with the `i/o` server before the content loads, so why do it before?

Comment: It works finel, but if there was some other more interesting way

Comment: Usually the application logic (connecting, listening to socket.io) should live in a singleton service (@Injectable()) which you can import to other components. Than you should just have some init function inside, that you will call from your root component after all the childs are initialized. I think this is better than including logic in components. Than you can use @Inject provide to insert different implementation of the singleton service (for testing, or different socket library, etc)